Why does this ASP.NET MVC controller hang the AppPool in IIS?
This is in C# ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6, .NET 4.8, MySql, IIS.
I seem to be getting a race condition here:
LogErr("set AppAgent start");

_AppWebsite = db.Websites
                .Where(x => x.Domain == Request.Url.Host)
                .SingleOrDefault();
LogErr("set AppAgent end");

My log shows "set AppAgent start" but not "set AppAgent start", so it is hanging on the db access. It doesn't seem to be giving an exception.
The hang / race is easy to catch after a fresh publish. If I make multiple requests while the site is starting up it will usually hang. It would probably happen at other times but I can't make those requests quickly enough to cause the hang once it's running.
Killing the AppPool will fix the hang.
Here's the controller. It's a base controller I derive from. I've removed a lot of code of course.
I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Globalization;

using PropertyDB;
using PropertyDB.Models;
using PropertyDB.Support;
using PropertySite.Models;
using PropertySite.Support;
using System.IO;

namespace PropertySite.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected DataContext db = new PropertyDB.DataContext();
        protected PageModel DefaultPageModel;

        private Website _AppWebsite; //cache for AppWebsite

        public Website AppWebsite
        {
            get
            {
                if (_AppWebsite == null)
                {
                    LogErr("set AppAgent start");
                    _AppWebsite = db.Websites.Where(x => x.Domain == Request.Url.Host).SingleOrDefault();
                    LogErr("set AppAgent end");
                }
                return _AppWebsite;
            }
        }

        public BaseController()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

            //init model for page

            string RequestPath = Request.Path;
            DefaultPageModel = new PageModel()
            {
                Website = AppWebsite,
                Route = RequestPath.Substring(1).Split('/'),
            };

            string PagePath = DefaultPageModel.Route[0];
            DefaultPageModel.Page = db.Pages
                                      .Where(x => x.WebsiteId == AppWebsite.Id)
                                      .Where(x => x.Path == PagePath)
                                      .SingleOrDefault();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (db != null)
                {
                    db.Dispose();
                    db = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}

and the table it is querying is below.  The table has 5 records.
CREATE TABLE `websites` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SellerId` int NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Domain` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MenuH` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  `MenuF` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  `CreatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeletedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubEndDate` date DEFAULT '2090-01-01',
  `Logo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i_SellerId` (`SellerId`),
  KEY `i_Domain` (`Domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;


I've tried moving the code from OnActionExecuting to the Initialize method, but it didn't help.

Why do you think it's a race condition, and why would it be a problem if it were? Sure, you are not following any singleton patter, so multithreaded access to the public Website AppWebsite would instantiate _AppWebsite multiple times, but that is not going to happen here. Have you actually verified there isn't an exception?

Please share the CREATE TABLE for the table it is querying.

private Website _AppWebsite; //cache for AppAgent in what way is this a cache. You are aware that each web request will new up a new instance of the controller (and thus that Website is not shared between requests)?

@mjwills it's a cache in the sense that it stores the value so it doesn't have to re requeried every time it's used.  Thanks.  I've also added the table details for you.

@GSerg I think its a race becasue of how it is triggered by 2 simultanious requests.  The web site just hangs then.  It might not be a race but it acts like a concurrency issue.  I don't think it throws an exception because elmah doesn't log one, my onexception handler doesn't log one, and the server doesn't return a 500 error.  I'm really stumped, it doesn't make sense.

Blocked queries aren't race conditions. They're caused by long-lived transactions, missing indexes or simply inefficient queries that access and lock far more rows than they need to. Single isn't the same as First as it tries to retrieve at least 2 items, to ensure only a single one exists

BTW this BaseController is trying to do what .NET Core's DI (or any DI container) already implement as scoped services. In any case, the correct way to implement such functionality is through middleware, not overriding the OnActionExecuting method

doesn't return a 500 error your code doesn't log anything so you can't know. Should something throw inside OnActionExecuting the action won't even run. If I make multiple requests does any of these requests start a transaction? The code is filtering on uniindexed columns so all queries take locks on all rows. If anything tries to update based on unindexed columns, it will take exclusive locks on all columns

it's a cahce in the sense no it's not. A new controller instance is created for every request, so _AppWebsite is always null.

@Panagiotis Kanavos its a cache within the current request, not across different requests.  Without it the db record would be queried multiple times.

@panagiotis-kanavos This isn't .NET Core unfortunately.  I'm using Single as there should only be one result.  There are 5 records in the table so no long running queries here.  I think EF6 does use a transaction even for a simple select.  The web site doesn't make any updates to the db at all.  This query is on the Domain feild, which is indexed.  My code does log ecxeptions, the sample here doesn't.  Thx.

That's not a deadlock either. The database would detect the deadlock and kill one of the connections that caused it. Post something that reproduces the problem so others can test it. Are you sure you have no code executing eg SELECT FOR UPDATE, either in the application or MySQL Workbench?

@panagiotis-kanavos Lets call it a hang then.  It also hangs on the dev machine so I know there's nothing else using the db.  If I can't get any help I will have to try cutting everything out, maybe I'lll get it down to something I can post here.

How many records are in your websites table? What charset are you using for Domain?

Why is DefaultPageModel a field?

@mjwills Do you think either of those might cause the problem?  I appreciate your help but don't want to get sidetracked.  The table is small, just 5 records.

@mjwills utf8mb3.  Can that cause the site to crash?

Can you show us the action method being invoked?

@mjwills Thanks, but the action itself isn't being executed, it never reaches that code.

This seems to be fixed now thanks to some housekeeping.  I was about to start cutting the app down to narrow down the cause, so I did some tidying up first.  I don't know the exact cause but here's what I did:

Updated all nuget packages.  This included a lot of minor version updates to EF and MySql.data.
I removed references in web.config to Owin components.  The nuget packages had been uninstalled, but these references remained.
Clean the project and rebuild.

I suspect it was the owin references in web.config causing the problem.
